# How to access a widget has the same level with the current widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, state-management

In my LoginFormState I have

```
final signInFormKey = LabeledGlobalKey<FormState>("login_form");

static LoginFormState of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.findAncestorStateOfType<LoginFormState>();
  }
```

My MainButton state have this line

```
LoginFormState.of(context)
                    .signInFormKey
                    .currentState
                    .validate()
```

And those both have the same parent, their parent is a stack widget:

```
[
Builder( builder: (BuildContext context) => AnimatedOpacity(
                    opacity: status == 0 ? 0 : 1,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                    child: LoginForm(),
                  ),
                ),
MainButton(),
]
```

when I call the function in the mainButton state it log the error below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you invoke the `LoginFormState.of()` method in your `MainButton` and it has no `LoginForm` ancestor.

That's your Widget tree:

- *some widget that you didn't post in code*

  - `Builder`

    - `AnimatedOpacity`
    - `LoginForm`
  - `MainButton`

See? There's no LoginForm "surrounding" `MainButton`.

What you may want to do is to declare a `LoginFormState` `GlobalKey` in the ancestor of both the `MainButton` and the `LoginForm`, and the closest one is the one I marked above in *cursive* and then pass it to both your `LoginForm` widget and `MainButton` as constructor parameters.

You can also create an `InheritedWidget` which would wrap both those widgets and expose the `SomeName.of()` method for you in both of them, you can also use the [provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), which is "An InheritedWidget but for humans" (as someone said it on Flutter Europe).

Comment: Thank for your advice. I solved it by make the key declare in the parent of the widgets